# How to use FTP or HTTP to copy database file 

Tags: android

In my app I am using the method of copying database file from assets folder.
It will increase the size of the apk. I want to copy it from the Internet when first time my app is run on the phone.
How i will give the FTP or HTTP in my code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to wrap your head around HTTPRequests:
http://www.tutorials-android.com//code_examples/How_to_post_a_non_blocking_HTTP_request_in_Android.rhtml

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

And make sure that is the first Activity to run in your chain of Activities:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Then finally how you deal with fetching from the SDCard:
I poked around in code.google.com and found this useful:
http://code.google.com/p/android-phpmanual/

More importantly:
http://code.google.com/p/android-phpmanual/source/browse/trunk/src/lu/mind/androidphpmanual/LocalFileContentProvider.java

and

http://code.google.com/p/android-phpmanual/source/browse/trunk/src/lu/mind/androidphpmanual/DownloadActivity.java

Hope that helps!